# Is it possible to create a big WindowsVPS from several DedicatedServer in openstack?

Tags: cloud, openstack, sharding

I need a WindowsVPS with a lot of hardware resources that are not available on a single DedicatedServer.

I'm wondering if I can create a big WindowsVPS with **three DedicatedServer resources** using **openstack**?

I want to connect to this created WindowsVPS through the **remote desktop(RDP)**.

Comment: No, that's not how it works.

Comment: @ceejayoz , tnx a lot. And do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Find a bigger server. Or, tell us why you need a big server, probably you can split its "big tasks" so they'll be able to run on several machines efficiently. For instance, for mass remote desktop services hosting there is an *RDS Farm* technology.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I want to generate a cloud using 3 DedicatedServer and then generate only one VPS from this cloud so that I can connect to it by remote desktop(RDP). In fact, I want the operation of increasing the resources to be done only by adding a new DedicatedServer to the cloud network.

Comment: So, what you planning to do in that system? Just connect via RDP and sit looking at the remote desktop? Or run some applications — which ones? // This is an XY problem. Certainly. You want more resources in the single system for some purpose (that's X) and you believe you can make a SSI cluster that would do what you want (that's Y). But you don't know how to make an SSI cluster either and just ask that. // We won't be able to help until you say what's what the original purpose. And, I am sure the solution won't be an SSI cluster, you are just thinking the wrong way.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov You are right. We have lunched our application on a windows server. Now the resources of our server are not responding to the MsSQL of this server. 
Unfortunately, we cannot separate the MsSQL of this application and move it to another Server. Also, our application does not have the ability to use MsSQL in the replication system.
Therefore, we hope that avoid the problem of server resources by creating a cloud. Also, due to business rules, we cannot use separate services such as Azure, etc.

Comment: No, it is impossible to increase performance of the database in that way. Absolutely. You *have* to search for other ways.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov tnx. Can you give me a starting point?